# How to add JTable to JTabbedPane in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I have a java desktop application that basically reads excels with apache poi (xls,xlsx) and also with BufferedReader for csv,I manage to get the first sheet of the excels and paint it on a JTable and pass it to a global JPanel then the user modifies the JTable and generates a new excel file, everytime the user loads an excel the JTable is remade and also repainted, the problem is now the excel can have more than 1 sheet, so I need to paint multiple JTable for each sheet and display each table on a different tab, I was starting by learning how to add on each tab a JTable but im not being able to do this, the way my program works is with 1 global JPanel, a global JTable and global JScrollPane, I have 3 methods, 1 for making table when its a xls, another 1 for making table for xlsx and finally 1 for making table for csv, in those methods I remove everything from my JPanel and add the global table modified to this JPanel, it works perfectly but now that I have this requeriment of printing multiple sheets I think that having them as global wont let me do it or will it?

I have tried using a global JTabbedPane in which for now I add a tab containing a JTable everytime the user loads an excel file, but its not working, I try to create a new JPanel locally in the method, then pass it the new JTable, then pass this JPanel to the JTabbedPane with the add() method, then pass this JTabbedPane to my global JPanel, but it won't work as I expected.

I have this class that a partner help me to implement because I was having trouble setting the image background so I had to use this, its the same as JPanel just that with that method to set the background, I also have a mehtod there that I use it to read a properties file that I have inside JAR when I do Maven Build, but the relevant in this class is that I use for having a image background because I couldn't do it by the other ways.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    // Atributo que guardara la imagen de Background que le pasemos.
    private ImageIcon background;
    private File file;

    // Metodo que es llamado automaticamente por la maquina virtual Java cada vez
    // que repinta
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        /*
         * Obtenemos el tamano del panel para hacer que se ajuste a este cada vez que
         * redimensionemos la ventana y se lo pasamos al drawImage
         */
        int width = this.getSize().width;
        int height = this.getSize().height;

        // Mandamos que pinte la imagen en el panel
        if (this.background != null) {
            g.drawImage(this.background.getImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);

        }

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    // Metodo donde le pasaremos la dirección de la imagen a cargar.
    public void pintar(String imagePath) {

        // Construimos la imagen y se la asignamos al atributo background.
        this.setOpaque(false);

        // this.background = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();

        this.background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagePath));
        System.out.println("Esta es la ruta de la  imagen : " + getClass().getResource(imagePath));

        repaint();
    }

    public Properties devolverProperties() throws IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream("configuracion.properties");
        properties.load(stream);
        stream.close();
        return properties;

    }

    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) { ImagePanel ima = new ImagePanel();
     * System.out.println(ima.devolverFile("/img/configuracion.properties")); }
     */
}
```

then in my main class called InterfazPrincipal I do the following:

```
public class InterfazPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ImagePanel image = new ImagePanel();

JLabel nombreFile = new JLabel("No se ha seleccionado ningun archivo");

Font fuente = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 12);

JScrollPane scrollsilloGlobal = new JScrollPane();

JTable tablaGlobal = new JTable();

JTabbedPane pestanas = new JTabbedPane();
```

Constructor:

```
public InterfazPrincipal() throws IOException {

        // Seteamos titulo y tamano
        setTitle("Aplicacion Excels");
        setSize(500, 500);
        // No se puede cambiar el tamano de la pantalla en ejecucion
        setResizable(false);
        // coloca la ventana en una posición relativa a un componente que le pasemos
        // como parametro. Pero si le pasamos null como parametro,
        // coloca a la ventana en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Posicionamiento absoluto.
        setLayout(null);
        // Salir al cerrar la app.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Pasamos la ruta de la imagen
        image.pintar("/img/fondoEmp.png");
        // Seteamos posicion en que se despliega el frame y si ancho y alto
        image.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        image.setLayout(null);

        labels();
        botones();
        this.add(image);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Then in my method after I have read the xls and have the table ready I wanna add it to the tab and to the interface like this:

```
tablaGlobal.setModel(model);
tablaGlobal.setBackground(Color.GRAY.darker());
tablaGlobal.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
tablaGlobal.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
scrollsilloGlobal.getViewport().add(tablaGlobal,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollsilloGlobal.setBounds(65, 130, 385, 120);
ImagePanel panel1=new ImagePanel();
panel1.add(scrollsilloGlobal);
panel1.setBounds(65, 130, 385, 160);
pestanas.add("First Table", panel1);
pestanas.setBounds(65, 130, 385, 160);
image.add(pestanas);
```

but its not working, it adds it but I have to click up left side of table to show the tab, and if I try to add another tab it will just override that tab.

Actual result: Displaying table without the tab until I click the upper left corner of the table, if I try to add more tabs it will override that tab.
Expected result: Adding multiple tabs with a JTable on each tab.

I have searched info about how to do this, I was trying like this (https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jtabbedpane/create-jtabbedpane-example/) it worked but not as expected, I think my problem is im not using a JFrame, im using JPanel only my JFrame is the main class, im sorry if I sound confusing im open to any kind of help or orientation.

Comment: There isn’t enough code to determine what’s going on, but your use of setBounds looks suspicious.  You should almost never call setBounds.  Normally, the LayoutManager of each container sets the bounds of its children.  Please edit your question and add the code for the ImagePanel class.

Comment: @VGR added bro, if I don't do the set bounds the things won't display, I can add more code if you need to, of the way im building the interface

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the Excel files. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Use non-null [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).  Also, you are adding a JScrollPane child incorrectly;  [that add method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,int%29) takes a constraints object and an index, not scroll pane constants.  Use [setViewportView](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29) instead.

Comment: @VGR Okay thank you mate I will try that when I get back to work, thank you :D, but so as you see it using the global variables won't affect me?

Comment: Since they are non-static, they should be fine… as long as you don’t plan to add more than one table.